# Why doesn't the Python 2 csv module support unicode?

Tags: python, csv, unicode

As you might know the Python 2 stdlib [`csv`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) module doesn't "properly" support unicode. It expects binary strings that it will write to the file as it gets them.

To me this always seemed a bit counter-intuitive as i would tell people to internally work with unicode strings and properly serialize things for the external world by opening files with `codecs.open(..., encoding='...')`, but in the `csv` module case you need to do this manually for the `lists` / `dicts` you pass in.

It always puzzled me why this is and now that a colleague asks me again, I have to admit that i don't know any reason for it other than "probably grown and never fixed".

It seems that even [PEP305](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0305/) already contained TODOs for unicode and references to `codecs.open`.

Is there some wise python guru here who knows and could enlighten us?

Answer (score 0):

Python 2 `csv` doesn't support Unicode because CSV doesn't support Unicode.

CSV as defined in RFC 4180 and in common usage is no more than a sequence of bytes. There is no standard to define how those bytes are mapped to readable text, and different CSV-handling tools have divergent behaviours. If Python's `csv` provided particular encoding rules they would be wrong in many cases. Better to let the user decide by manually encoding/decoding using whichever convention works for that application.

Python 3 `csv` gains Unicode support in as much as it has to talk to text IO streams (as these are now much more common). These have their own encoding, but if you use one with its default encoding for CSV, the results will still be wrong as often as not.